# EXCEL: SUMIF() as true statement to IF()

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a 2 sheet workbook. One showing a basic readout of summed data and a second with dummy exported data from sending emails to people. I need to check IF datestamp cell is equal to today, Sum the emails sent to a certain company.

But my formula only ever returns false. If I test with different options like datestampTODAY(), or =TODAY() everything still returns false. I thought it might have to do with the datestamp being a full UTC datestamp while TODAY() only being the date, but I tested a simple =TODAY()>dummydatestamp and it returned true, so I think it might also have to do with nesting the SUMIF as the TRUE response to the IF.

Thoughts?

`=IF(LEFT(Table2[Last Contacted At],10)<TODAY(),SUMIF(Table2[Company],[@Account],Table2[Last Contacted At]))`

## [image: First Tab]

[image: Second Tab]

Comment: What kind of data is `Last Contacted At`? Does Excel recognize it as a date or it is a string? My first thought is that `Left()` returns a string so you're checking `"2019-09-25"<TODAY()` which is always false. Try `DateValue(Left(~))<Today()` and let us know if that works.

Comment: @EngineerToast, your point makes sense and resolved the error that was popping up, so thank you, but now it just returns "0".

Now the formula:
`=IF(DATEVALUE(LEFT(Table2[Last Contacted At],10))>TODAY()-20,SUMIF(Table2[Company],[@Account],Table2['# Sent Emails]), 0)`

Comment: It's returning `0` because the formula changed from `IF(<thing>,SUMIF(~))` to `IF(<thing>,SUMIF(~),0)` so it'll return `0` instead of the default `FALSE`. Can you re-upload the second screenshot but with `C2` selected so we can see its contents in the formula bar?

Comment: @EngineerToast, right right. I've updated the image with C2 selected.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify things and use COUNTIF, like this:

[image]

This is the formula you need:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table2[Company],[@Account],Table2[Last Contacted At],"<TODAY()")
```

To sum the '# of sent emails column', use SUMIFS:

[image]

```
=SUMIFS(Table2['# Sent Emails],Table2[Company],[@Account],Table2[Last Contacted At],"<TODAY()")
```

Comment: When I copy paste either formula, I get a generic Excel error "There is a problem with your formula". Thoughts?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Also, did you change the text "Table2" to the name of your table?

Comment: I'm using Office 16. Table2 is the literal reference in the formula. It automatically filled that when selecting the column I needed, and works for my other formulas.

Comment: @CharlesWatson Owen had a slightly different field name than you did. [Last Contact At] vs. [Last Contact*ed* At]. Try them now.